# WooCommerce lottery pick number: Add leading zeros to lottery numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, numbers

1. I want to edit my paid WooCommerce plugin. It generates lottery numbers in 1, 2, 3, 4, and I want it in 4 digits like 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004.

   ```
    function woocommerce_quantity_input( $args = array(), $product = null, $echo = true ) {
        if ( is_null( $product ) ) {
            $product = $GLOBALS['product'];
        }

        $defaults = array(
            'input_id'    => uniqid( 'quantity_' ),
            'input_name'  => 'quantity',
            'input_value' => '1',
            'classes'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_classes', array( 'input-text', 'qty', 'text' ), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', -1, $product ),
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 0, $product ),
            'step'        => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 1, $product ),
            'pattern'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_pattern', has_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval' ) ? '[0-9]*' : '' ),
            'inputmode'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_inputmode', has_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval' ) ? 'numeric' : '' ),
        );

        $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

        // Apply sanity to min/max args - min cannot be lower than 0.
        $args['min_value'] = max( $args['min_value'], 0 );
        $args['max_value'] = 0 < $args['max_value'] ? $args['max_value'] : '';

        // Max cannot be lower than min if defined.
        if ( '' !== $args['max_value'] && $args['max_value'] < $args['min_value'] ) {
            $args['max_value'] = $args['min_value'];
        }

        ob_start();

        if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id() , '_lottery_use_pick_numbers', true ) === 'yes' && "yes" !== get_post_meta( $product->get_id() , '_lottery_pick_numbers_random', true ) && $args['input_id'] != 'qty_dip') {
            echo '<div class="quantity">
                <input type="hidden" id="' .esc_attr( $args['input_id'] ) . '" class="qty" name="' . esc_attr( $args['input_name'] ) . '" value="' . esc_attr($args['input_value']) . '" />
                '.$args['input_value'].'
            </div>';
        } else {
            wc_get_template( 'global/quantity-input.php', $args );
        }


        if ( $echo ) {
            echo ob_get_clean(); // WPCS: XSS ok.
        } else {
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too abstract but you can achieve your desired output using WordPress inbuilt formatting function `zeroise()`.

Official documentation for [WordPress `zeroise()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/zeroise/)

WordPress *(version 5.5.3)* source code for [`zeroise()` function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5.3/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2650-L2669)